# Element-wise division in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

My question seems very easy but I can't seem to find any resources on this. I would like to symbolically do elementwise devision using SymPy. What I would like to do is something like

```
# input_array
arr1 = [2, 27, 2, 21, 23]
arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  
# output_array
out = np.divide(arr1, arr2)
```

And receive the output of the form

```
[1, 9, 0.5, 4.2, 3.83333333]
```

Except using symbols instead of actual numbers in Sympy. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: What is the output you expect?  arr1/arr2 or [arr1[0]/arr2[0], ........ ]?

Comment: Wherw are the symbols?  A list?  Some sort of `sympy` structure (array, vector, matrix)?  They could be in a numpy array, but that's not a very robust option.

Comment: See also [sympy element wise division of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768981/sympy-element-wise-division-of-vector).  In this case, you could just calculate `out = [a1/a2 for a1,a2 in zip(arr1,arr2)]`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430237/python-how-to-multiply-matrix-with-symbols-and-0s for a discussion of using symbols with `numpy`.  It's possible, but with limitations, since the resulting arrays will be object dtype, not the fast and powerful numeric dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python, the list comprehension as @JohanC indicated, is a simple way to go. If you want to use such a thing regularly, then creating a helper in your own library file (or pythonstartups) might be good idea, e.g.

```
>>> elwise = lambda a, b, f: [f(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
>>> div = lambda a, b: elwise(a,b, lambda x,y: x/y)
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> div(a,b)
[0.25, 0.4, 0.5]
```